# WPF: How to set bool to true from DataTemplate for Button?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatemplate

I know it is possible to do this by working with ICommand, but since this is the only place in my whole project where this is needed, I am asking myself, if there is maybe a better solution than implementing RelayCommand and ICommand and an additional method in my otherwise property-only class?

Maybe my scenario may help here:
I have a ListView which is bound to a list of properties (this is a custom-class I made to display those). 
I have a button in eacht row of entries, that I want to set the "IsToDelete"-Property to true.

If "IsToDelete" is true, all the controls I show in my ListView will collapse.

The whole logic is up to this point in DataTemplates, the one for my button looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DeleteButtonTemplate">
  <Button Name="bt_Delete" 
   Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}, Path=ItemSource.DeleteClicked}">
    <Image Height="16" Width="16" Source="Images\RecycleBin\VSO_RecycleBin_16x.png"/>
    <Button.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsToDelete}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </Button.Style>
  </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

Note the command in this DataTemplate is currently not working as intended, that is why I even got to the question ;)

In the optimal case I'd just have to do something like:

```
<Setter Property="{Binding IsToDelete}" Value="True"/>
```

So, is there a way to solve it like this or at least in a less complicated way than ICommand with RelayCommand?

Comment: do you want to set `Visibility` of `Button` to `Collapsed` after clicking at the `Button`?

Comment: How are you assigning the datacontext to page/button and where is this command an IsToDelete property is defined?

Comment: @StepUp yes, thats exactly what i want to do, but since this isn't the only control to change, I need to set the boolean IsToDelete to true.

Comment: @KyloRen I assign the Itemssource in my code-behind to the listview, where this template is copied from.
I added the ICommand as simple Property to the Property-class, the IsToDelete-Boolean is in this class, too.

Comment: @ExoWork what is the datacontext your button is getting? and where is IsToDelete property is defined?

Comment: @KyloRen To be honest, I think you may be giving me a direction to where i am looking ... I add a datacontext to the TabItem, where the ListView is written in, datacontext is my "ViewModel"-Class (yes, thats the name :)) Should I set one for the button? And if so, maybe I just don't understand datacontext not correctly, but how do I "connect" the class with the instanced variable of that class? Additionally, IF this is my problem, why did this never bother me before Oo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use `ToggleButton` and bind `IsChecked` property to `IsToDelete` property of a viewModel?

simplified example with `ItemsControl`

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ToggleButton Content="X" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsToDelete}"/>
                <Border Width="100"                                
                        Background="MediumPurple" 
                        Margin="5">

                    <Border.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Border">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>                                        
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsToDelete}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Border.Style>

                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>            
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: ... Sometimes I get so damn focused on one problem that I miss the easy path ^^ I still would like to know, IF it were possible with just a button.
Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Click eventhandler of the Button. Then you don't need any Commands.

```
private void bt_Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var btn = sender as Button;
    YourClass dc = btn.DataContext as YourClass;
    dc.IsToDelete = true;
}
```

I don't really like this solution, but I think, it would work.